# Get a flash object to be next to an input field

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with getting two elements lined up properly.

Here is my HTML:

```
<input class='pretty-border' id='shareinput' value='afdsdasfdasfadsff' />
<span>
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
            width="14"
            height="14"
            id="clippy" >
        <param name="movie" value="/clippy.swf"/>
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
        <param NAME="FlashVars" value="id=clip_text">
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF">
        <embed src="/clippy.swf"
               width="14"
               height="14"
               name="clippy"
               quality="high"
               allowScriptAccess="always"
               type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
               pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
               FlashVars="id=clip_text"
               bgcolor="#FFFFFF"
        />
    </object>
</span>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
input.pretty-border {
  float:left;
  font-size:1em;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 4px solid #c9deff;
}
```

Unfortunately, there is a line break between the objects as can be seen in the attached picture. How can I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a link or this private?

Comment: Sorry, it is HTML that is only on my local PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try giving both elements the same class name then put the float:left for that class, not just the input element.

```
.sameclass {                
     float:left;                
 }
```

Comment: That worked after I got rid of the float: left in the parent's div too!

Answer (score 0):

setting `display:inline` on the object seems to work (tested in Chrome & FF)

```
span object {display:inline;}
```